# bash script for rsync ssh user input

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, rsync

I am trying to write an rsync script that would take the user inputed path to the source file and send it over to a another user inputed path on the remote machine.

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo -e "What is the directory on the local machine you want to send"

read sourcedir


SOURCEDIR = :$sourcedir

echo -e "What is the directory on the GPU box you want to send these files over to?"

read destdir

DESTDIR = :$destdir

rsync -avu -e "ssh -p xxxx" $SOURCEDIR $DESTDIR user@remote.computer --progress
```

When i execute the script i get the following error

```
-bash: DESTDIR: command not found
building file list ...
rsync: link_stat "/path/to/script/user@remote.computer" failed: No such file or directory (2)
0 files to consider
sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-51/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

Would appreciate your advice/suggestions on writing this script correctly.

PS. I have removed some sensitive information from the output, but rest assured the format is consistent with the output from the computer.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Problem

In bash, assignments work only without spaces around the `=`:

```
variable=value      # assign "value" to variable "variable"
```

```
variable = value    # call program "variable" with arguments "=" and "value"
```

To fix your problem, remove the spaces around the `=`.

#### Better Solution

Note that special variables (like `PDW`, `RANDOM`, ...) in bash are ALL UPPERCASE by convention. When writing scripts, it is recommended to use lowercase variables to prevent accidental name collisions.

The difference between `DESTDIR` and `destdir` is not clear by the variable name. `DESTDIR` is used only once. I think it would be easier and clearer to write

```
echo ...
read sourcedir
echo ...
read destdir
rsync ... ":$sourcedir" ":$destdir" ...
```

Comment: Thank you! this kind of worked. I just dont know where the files got sent.